# PostgreSQL 9.4 \copy Error

Tags: postgresql, csv, squirrel-sql

I am attempting to copy data from a csv file into a postgresql database, and am using the following line to do so:

`\copy album_tracks FROM 'C:\Users\wMogerty\Desktop\test.csv' WITH (format csv, header true);`

However, I am getting the following error and am unsure why:

`Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
 Position: 1
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 0`

Thanks for any help

Comment: `\copy` is `psql` metacommand, not an SQL statement - what is your client?

Comment: @VaoTsun I am using Squirrel SQL.

Comment: if file is located on server use `copy` without backslash, if file is on client side, I don't know if Squirrel has any workaround for `copy from stdin`

Answer (score 0):

`\copy` is a command in the `psql` client. It is not supported by the PostgreSQL server. Nor is it part of `libpq` so it's not supported by alternative clients like PgAdmin-III etc.

You'll need to copy the file to the server yourself and use the `COPY` command to load it into the database. Or if your client has another interface to the underlying `COPY ... FROM STDIN` feature used by `\copy`, like an "import table" or "bulk load" option, you can use that.

I wonder if we should make the PostgreSQL server's parser detect attempts to run `\copy` as a SQL query and give a better error? Sounds like a great patch for a new developer to try.